# Return special characters in html correctly from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, special-characters

I have an angular function that returns rounded numbers. If the number was rounded, it will add the "almost equal to" sign (≈) in front of the returned number. The problem is, it's not displayed as a html character, but as the characters `&asymp;` instead. How is this fixed?

```
$scope.roundAprox = function(num) { //Returns almost equal to before rounded number if number was rounded
    var numRounded = Math.round(num);
    if (numRounded != num) //Has been rounded
        return '&asymp;' + numRounded;
    else //Has not been rounded
        return numRounded;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `≈` character itself (instead of an HTML entity in a context that doesn't expect HTML).

Alternatively, use a JavaScript unicode escape sequence (`\u2248`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that already, and unfortunately didn't work. The ≈ character doesn't display correctly in Notepad++, and in the browser a �-sign appears.

Comment: Then you need to ensure that the encoding Notepad++ to save as and the encoding the server is configured to claim the document is using (in the Content-Type header) are both UTF-8.

Comment: Ah yes, works like a charm, thank you! The problem was that I was coding in ANSI. I went to menu Format -> Convert to UTF-8 (without BOM). Using the JavaScript unicode escape sequence (\u2248) worked even when coding in ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
 return '≈' + numRounded;
```